# How is that Omega Supreme's arm from Transformers Energon seems to be no other than the Macross spaceship from SDF-Macross?

Tags: transformers, macross

I was looking a Youtube video about Omega Supreme where they showed Transformers Energon version of him. And I noticed his arm looks almost identically to the SDF-Macross spaceship from SDF-Macross.

[Omega Supreme Transformers Energon](https://tfwiki.net/wiki/File:EnergonOmegaSupreme_toy.jpeg)

[Macross spaceship series version](https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcR-eFCKj5thM3m6AM64ukOj9LBU4vYZWjo_eA&usqp=CAU)

[Macross spaceship movie version](https://www.google.com/imgres?imgurl=https%3A%2F%2Fstatic.wikia.nocookie.net%2Fmacross%2Fimages%2F3%2F3c%2FSDF1-Plus_Cruiser.gif%2Frevision%2Flatest%3Fcb%3D20131006192250&imgrefurl=https%3A%2F%2Fmacross.fandom.com%2Fwiki%2FSDF-1_Macross&tbnid=N3dpT4omcYakmM&vet=10CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI2Jq11pnG9wIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY..i&docid=smWb9uN6jUtGoM&w=900&h=381&itg=1&q=macross%20spaceship%20movie%20version&ved=0CAMQxiAoAGoXChMI2Jq11pnG9wIVAAAAAB0AAAAAEAY)

How did this happen? Where some designers from Macross involved in Transformers Energon, did they get a license or something, or is this supposed to look different enough as for qualifying as a new design?

Notice Wikipedia claims some apparently uncredited involvement in Transformers G1 designs from a character designer from SDF-Macross

Comment: However, the G1 Omega Supreme does not have the resemblance you are interested in.